# PHP json/ajax not working on remote host

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have developed a site on my local machine and got it working fine, but after uploading it to my remote host, the ajax/json calls fail to run.

I have checked for any html being written before the redirects are run and the only things I can find are where I am echoing json_encode($return).

Is this the problem? And if so does anyone know how I can fix this.? An alternative to using echo maybe??

thanks

Code below with labels as to where I think the problem might be...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#addStory input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('editor.php', $("#addStory").serialize(), function(result) {
            alert(result.adminList);
        }, "json");
    });
});

</script>



<form name="addStory" action="" method="post" id="addStory">
    <input type="text" id="test_text" name="test_text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And here's editor.php...

```
<?php

header('application/json');

$return = array();
$return['adminList'] = "Hello World!";
echo json_encode($return);

?>
```

The "Hello World" alert does not happen...

Comment: Where is the `header('location: ...)` call? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: That's a good point... I've picked a bad example! However, this shows the ajax not running properly because the I am using a javascript redirect in this example. If the user enters correct login details $return['adminlist'] populates the javascript redirect value. Hope this makes a bit of sense, I'm not sure how best to explain.

Comment: Well what errors are you getting? Is there a javascript error or is your php not returning? You need more information for us to come up with an answer.  However my answer below does point out one error in your php.

Comment: I'm not getting any javascript errors as far as I can tell. The php is running fine as all the sessions are being set correctly. I'll see if I can work out how to throw back any errors that I might not be seeing currently.

Comment: If you want to display the errors then just alert the return in your javascruipt ajax success statement.

Comment: changed window.location=result.adminList; to alert(result.adminList); and no alert appears.

Comment: If you are getting json you should use getJson function rather than post.  You can use post but you need to set the return type and convert to json I think (I may be wrong).  Otherwise it is just a string being returned.  I think your error is trying to do `result.adminList` on a string.

Comment: Hi @JonTaylor... I've simplified my code to try to make the problem easier to understand. I think the redirect was a red herring.

Comment: have you tried just `alert(result)` to see what it does?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13848/discussion-between-tom-and-jon-taylor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem you do have is the second `header('application/json')` is placed after the output of the first SQL query. This is only the case if `$row['column_name'] == 0` is true though.

If it is always going to return json then just set this right at the top of the php code to avoid confusion later on.

```
<?php
    header('application/json');

    //all your sql etc here

?>
```

I also noticed during our discussion that your header is actually incorrect.  It should be

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Removing it would also work however this is probably a bad idea since this serves the purpose of telling the recipient what type of data to expect.

Another point is that your current ajax should really be taking advantage of the `getJSON()` function in jQuery which will automatically give you back a json object.

```
$.getJSON('example.php', function(data) {
    //use data as a json object
});
```

Comment: If moved this as a one off to the top of the page and the PHP stopped running. What's really odd about this is that it works perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: @Tom ive edited my answer, hopefully this covers everthing we talked about, note the header change too, not sure if you got my last message in the chat.